# Line of code is ran even tho it shouldn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my own moving solution for unity.
Here's the code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        //Movement
        HandleMouseLooking(canLook); //HandleMouseLooking() should go before HandleMoving()   
        HandleMoving(canMove); //HandleMoving() and HandleCrouching() have the same importance so it doesn't matter
        HandleCrouching(canCrouch);
        HandleLedgeClimbing(canClimb);
        HandleSprinting(canSprint); //HandleSprinting() must be the last Handle of the Movement category
    }


bool[] DetectLedge()
    {
        /*
         * table of truth:
         * indexes:
         *   0       1        2
         * upper | lower | canClimb
         *   0   |   0   |    0     /0
         *   1   |   0   |    0     /1
         *   0   |   1   |    1     /2
         *   1   |   1   |    0     /3
        */

        bool[] ledgeInfo = new bool[3] { false, false, false }; //0
        ledgeInfo[0] = Physics.CheckBox(upperLedgeDetector.position, upperLedgeDetector.lossyScale, upperLedgeDetector.rotation, 128);
        ledgeInfo[1] = Physics.CheckBox(lowerLedgeDetector.position, lowerLedgeDetector.lossyScale, lowerLedgeDetector.rotation, 128);
        ledgeInfo[2] = ledgeInfo[1] && !ledgeInfo[0] ? true : false;

        return ledgeInfo;
    } 

    void HandleLedgeClimbing(bool isEnabled)
    {
        if(isEnabled)
        {
            Debug.Log(DetectLedge()[0] + " " + DetectLedge()[1] + " " + DetectLedge()[2]);
            if(DetectLedge()[2])
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Ledge!");

                canMove = false; //<--------------------Here it is!

                Vector3 calculatedPos = Vector3.zero;
                RaycastHit hit;
                Physics.Raycast(upperLedgeDetector.position, Vector3.down, out hit, 3f, 128);
                calculatedPos = new Vector3(lowerLedgeDetector.position.x, upperLedgeDetector.position.y - hit.distance, lowerLedgeDetector.position.z);
                if(transform.position != calculatedPos)
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, calculatedPos, Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

That's all the code that I believe is causing the issue.
Okay, so now to explain what's not working. Whenever I run the scene my player stops moving.
This is not expected at all because the only reason why it should stop moving is if the `canMove` variable is false, but I never set it to be false.
Now the only place in the code where it does change from true to false is in the `HandleLedgeClimbing()` void. But it should never come to it being set to false.

**I marked it's location with a big arrow.**

Now, I'm not an expert, but I'm pretty sure that everything in an `if statement` only runs if the condition in the if statement is true. So why is **only** `canMove = false;` ran when the if statement is false, which is checked by that `Debug.Log(DetectLedge()[0] + " " + DetectLedge()[1] + " " + DetectLedge()[2]);` *(which when I run the scene return false for all three variables; note: only the last variable is being checked in the if statement)*.

Also, yes, you read that right,  "**only**"

For some reason, nothing else in that if statement gets called! That's why I put the `Debug.LogWarning("Ledge!");` there, to see what causes the if statement to be true all of the sudden. But it was never called! Kind of *creepy* haha-

**TL/DR:** A part of the code is called when it shouldn't be possible for it to ever be called under the conditions we are presented in the scene. Best part is: only a specific line is called. Not even the whole block. I want to eliminate this from happening.

*Condition: DetectLedge[2] must be true for the if statement to be run. The debugging proves it's always false (unless we come near a ledge) and prior testing fortifies the fact.*

Comment: "Best part is: only a specific line is called" - that's not true. C# has been around for over 20 years. The compiler works. It's 99.9999999% that you've got something wrong with your code.

Comment: You should use proper debugging instead of Debug logs to track your variable changes. If the if statement is not actually executed then the variable is either being updated somewhere else or it was never actually set to true anywhere.

Comment: You really need a [mcve] for us to demonstrate the behaviour that you're seeing. Otherwise this is purely a faith exercise.

Comment: Calling `DetectLedge()[0] + " " + DetectLedge()[1] + " " + DetectLedge()[2]` then `if (DetectLedge()) ...` means you're calling `DetectLedge()` four times. How do you know that the value for `DetectLedge()[2]` doesn't change between the third and the fourth call?

Comment: Humor me; make the code like: `var dl2 = DetectLedge()[2]; Debug.Log(DetectLedge()[0] + " " + DetectLedge()[1] + " " + dl2);
            if(dl2)` then send a screenshot of the debugger paused on canMove; I want to see dl2 as false just inside the if

Comment: Please start [**Debugging your code** with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) .. `c#` (and any program at all) doesn't simply do stuff without you telling it to do it ;)

Comment: @Enigmativity ok to be honest there is no chance that the behaviour changes between the third and fourth call ;) They are executed right after each other within the same frame -> no parameters will have changed ;) .... of course this dosn't mean that the fact that four `bool[]` are created and then immediately thrown away is pretty much unnecessary ^^ @OP If something you should rather use `void DetectLedge(out bool up, out bool down, out bool canClimp)` or something like that ^^

Comment: @derHugo - You're betting that the c# compiler has a bug over the OP's code?

Comment: @Enigmativity no ... I'm betting that OP isn't reading the console correctly ... if you log somthing **every frame** it is pretty likely that you just didn't see the one log you where looking for ... rather debug using breakpoints and you don't need the log at all and can't miss it

Comment: @Anu6is true, I should. But when I say *only* that one line runs, then I mean it. The code after that part doesn't run either. Specifically talking about this: `if(transform.position != calculatedPos)
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, calculatedPos, Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: @Enigmativity okay you actually posted *one* somewhat cool comment. To answer your question, it's kind of ironic you keep bringing up c# compiler over and over again, when I don't think you understand how it works. 
Talking about the way code is ran on it's own tho, yes those callings are different, but they are *the same* since they use the same information, therefore, should give the same results. How do we know they use the same information? *Here comes the fun part and why I dislike your comments so much:* because it's all of those are ran in the same frame. More could be added, but can't

Comment: @derHugo now that you mentioned it.. I think I'll change it from `bool[]` to a `void` for perfomance, and overally, easier handling in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UHM**
I fixed it... in the weirdest possible way? I'm not sure at all what caused the issue, but if anybody knows it, please share. Some people could find it interesting.

Anyways, here is the fix:

```
EdgeDetectInformation DetectLedge()
    {
        /*
         * table of truth:
         * indexes:
         *   0       1        2
         * upper | lower | canClimb
         *   0   |   0   |    0     /0
         *   1   |   0   |    0     /1
         *   0   |   1   |    1     /2
         *   1   |   1   |    0     /3
        */

        bool[] ledgeInfo = new bool[3] { false, false, false }; //0
        ledgeInfo[0] = Physics.CheckBox(upperLedgeDetector.position, upperLedgeDetector.lossyScale, upperLedgeDetector.rotation, 128);
        ledgeInfo[1] = Physics.CheckBox(lowerLedgeDetector.position, lowerLedgeDetector.lossyScale, lowerLedgeDetector.rotation, 128);
        ledgeInfo[2] = ledgeInfo[1] && !ledgeInfo[0] ? true : false;

        return new EdgeDetectInformation(ledgeInfo[0], ledgeInfo[1], ledgeInfo[2]);
    }
```

Basically, instead of a `bool[]` I used a struct. This was *sort of* @derHugo 's idea, so thank you for that!

And in the other function, instead of calling it over and over in the `Debug.Log()` I did this:

```
 void HandleLedgeClimbing(bool isEnabled)
    {
        if(isEnabled)
        {
            EdgeDetectInformation EDI = DetectLedge();
            Debug.Log(EDI.upper + " " + EDI.lower + " " + EDI.canClimb);
            if(EDI.canClimb)
            ...
```

And... **that** fixed it.

Comment: I can't mark this as an answer yet, relax.

Comment: Are you saying that calling it once fixed it?

Comment: Lol that was clearly not my idea :'D .. my idea is mainly not even use an array at all! This is unnecessary Garbage Collector waste ^^

Comment: @derHugo that's why I said "*sort of*" :)

Comment: @Enigmativity you never said I should do that, you just kept pointing out the obvious. And the obvious was: the code was broken.